# Perform Cisco's DNS Doctoring on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, firewall, pf, cisco

How to perform a change in the DNS response from a DNS server to be a different IP address than the DNS server actually answered for a given name?

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_tech_note09186a0080094aee.shtml

Currently using PF (Packet Filter) on FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE.

Please help.